# Checking a list if a certain string exist in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

How can i check if a list has certain string in salesforce.
For example I have :
`anotherList` which is from controller and has 
this value `[NAME_A, NAME_B, NAME_C]`

Then in my page:

```
    <apex:repeat var="list" value="{!tesList}">
        <input type="checkbox" style="display:{!IF(CONTAINS(anotherList, list['name']), '','none')}" value="{!list['name']}" />
    </apex:repeat>
```

But i got an error saying that `Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'CONTAINS()'. Expected Text, received Object`

So parameters should only be Strings right? But how can i do something like this in Visualforce page?

```
<!-- JSTL sample -->
    <c:forEach var="list" items="${testList}">
            <c:if test="${fn:contains(anotherList, list.name)}">
                <input type="checkbox"  value="${list.name}" />
            </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing ['name'] since the repeat is already iterating over the values in the tesList

Comment: Hmmm i havent but i'll check.

Comment: @Eric Nope, it is still looking for text. I guess i have to create and actionFunction if there's no other way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is apparently no support of visualforce text functions for apex lists. 
While pure output of the list content on the visualforce page works perfect, an attempt to access a list with any text function will produce an error. Lets try to

Apex class:

```
testList = new List<String>{'NAME_A','NAME_B','NAME_C'};
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<!-- The following output works good as if it where a string -->
testList: {!testList}
```

On the page: `testList: [NAME_A, NAME_B, NAME_C]`

What if we could to convert the list to string somehow directly on the visualforce page? Let's try to use a magic `apex:variable` tag and assign a list to it.

But with one trick: we will concatenate it *with an empty string*:

```
<apex:variable var="list" value="{!''}{!testList}" />
```

Now let's try again to use a CONTAINS function that actually works only with strings:

```
NAME_A: {!IF(CONTAINS(list, 'NAME_A'),'OK','FALSE')} <br/>
BLAAHH: {!IF(CONTAINS(list, 'BLAAHH'),'OK','FALSE')}
```

Well, it works just awesome!

```
NAME_A: OK 
BLAAHH: FALSE
```

In your case it could look like:

```
<apex:variable var="list" value="{!''}{!anotherList}" />

<apex:repeat var="list" value="{!tesList}">
    <input type="checkbox" style="display:{!IF(CONTAINS(anotherList, list['name']), '','none')}" value="{!list['name']}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: You will need to be careful with this approach as it is doing string matching rather than matching on elements in a List. For example if your list was `new List<String>{'NAME B','NAME ABC','NAME C'};` and you searched for `NAME A` it would find that string even though the String that was in the List was `NAME ABC`

Comment: it's kinda confusing since the var in variable is also list and also for repeat..

Comment: @BarCotter Yes this is a tricky one and I would better use an apex for such comparison. But it is always interesting to crack out some "undocumented" functionality :)